# Whats wrong with how I'm using the scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a program that allow me to look through java files on my computer and see if all of the braces match up, so there are as many { as } and no } before a matching {. It lets me select a file, and then after I do it says that I No such element exception and that no line was found. The other half of the time it just runs forever, making me think I set an infinite loop somehow. Any tips with the scanner or while loop would be appreciated.

```
public class BraceChecker {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int response = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    boolean end = true;

    if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(f.toString());
        String line;
        ArrayListStack Stack1 = new ArrayListStack();
        while ((line = scan1.nextLine()) != null && end) {
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                if (line.charAt(i) == '{') {
                    Stack1.push('{');

                }
                if (line.charAt(i) == '}') {
                    if (Stack1.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("Braces Are Unbalanced");
                        end = false;
                        i = line.length();
                    } else {
                        Stack1.pop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (end == true && Stack1.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Braces are Balanced");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you step through the program in a debugger, while it's processing one of the problematic files? If not, that might be a good place to start.

Comment: But what about when it says line not found?

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
 while ((line = scan1.nextLine()) != null && end)
```

Use the scanner's hasNextLine method instead. nextLine throws a NoSuchElement if you try to scan a line that isn't there (ie, if you try to go off the end of the file)

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems in this :

```
Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(f.toString());
```

the Scanner should scan the File not the String representation of it , else it would scan litterally that string from `f.toString()`, which would be the name of the file,  so use :

```
new Scanner(f);// the file itself not its String representation
```

Then about the NoSuchElement error. It's a problem with the condition you wrote for the while loop. Although it seems right to put != null , if the line isn't there , the `scanner.nextLine()` doesn't return null , it throws a NoSuchElementException.

So to fix this try:

```
 String line ;
 while(scanner1.hasNext()){ //hasNext() means the sanner has a next line 
   line = scanner1.nextLine();
 }
```